# Why doesn't Powershell If Statement evaluate the exit status of commands it is given?

Tags: bash, powershell

In bash, I can do this:

```
if cd $some_directory; then
    rm *
else
    echo "Could not change directory! Aborting." 1>&2
    exit 1
fi
```

The if statement will execute if the exit status is 0 because the if evaluates the exit status.

Why doesn't the Powershell if statement do the same? If I wanted to check the exit status I have to check if $? evaluates to true or false afterward.

Comment: Powershell command normally don't return error code values when executing. If something goes wrong they will thrown an exception. These can be caught with try-catch statements. It's a different programming model.

Comment: @n3wjack - Why did the developers do this? Is it so that try-catch could be implemented and used?

Comment: Exceptions & try-catch statements are how errors are handled in e.g. Java & C#, while (integer) error codes are more C-style. Powershell uses a lot of .NET components, so the developers chose that model I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The If statement is evaluating the result of the Output stream, not the Error stream.  If you want to evaluate the Error stream in the If, redirect the Error stream:

```
if (cd $some_directory 2>&1)
  {echo "Could not change directory! Aborting." }
```

Powershell cmdlets don't output the result status to the output stream by default because typically you're going to be sending the result down the pipeline to cmdlets and functions expecting a particular object type, and you don't what those status codes polluting that stream.

Comment: Personally I find this code rather hacky. I know it matches the bash style statements, but I'd rather see a Test-Path to check for the folder, and not bother executing a failing CD statement if it doesn't exist. :)
Anyway, not what was asked, but more a programming style preference. :)

Comment: @n3wjac - It's not what I'd write for myself, but it seemed the path of least resistance for a demonstration.

Answer (score -1):

In PowerShell you use `Test-Path $some_directory` to check if a folder exists. It returns a boolean.

So that would look like this, while avoiding any errors being thrown on failing cd statements.
It's cleaner IMO than catching the exit code on a failing statement.

```
if (test-path $some_directory) {
   cd $some_directory
   del *
} else {
  echo "Could not change..."
}
```

Comment: That's good, but I mean the if in bash will evaluate the exit status no matter the command, why can't powershell do the same is what I'm after. Never mind I saw your comment above. Why the different model?

Comment: `cd` doesn't check for existence, it tries to change the current working directory, too. It can fail because of other reasons than non-existence, e.g. permissions.